# Base table or view not found after upload, but working using localhost

Tags: php, html, database, phpmyadmin, wamp

Good morning, I've created a page where users can send information using a form. It works perfectly fine when I use WAMP Server then I started uploading it to the hosting and now I get an error everytime I click submit.

Here's the error:

[image: Error]

Here's the insert-message.php:

```js
<?php
require_once ('database.php');

if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
    $day = $_POST['day'];
    $month = $_POST['month'];
    $year = $_POST['year'];
    $empname = $_POST['empname'];
    $position = ($_POST['position']);
    $account = $_POST['account'];
    $platform = $_POST['platform'];
    $processor = $_POST['processor'];
    $ram = $_POST['ram'];
    $monitor = $_POST['monitor'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $headset = $_POST['headset'];
    {
        $database->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $insert_query = "INSERT INTO tbl_pcrequest (day, month, year, empname, position, account, platform, processor, ram, monitor, phone, headset)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        $insert = $database->prepare($insert_query);
        $insert->execute(array($day, $month, $year, $empname, $position, $account, $platform, $processor, $ram, $monitor, $phone, $headset));

        echo "<script>alert('Successfully sent!'); window.location='index.php'</script>";
    }
}
?>
```

Database Schema:

[image: DB Schema]

PS: I've already changed all database connection credentials to my hosting credentials, don't worry.

Please let me know if you need something.

Comment: Have you created the database/tables on the live server?

Comment: Yes I've already uploaded it

Comment: Don't link images, juste paste the error text using the code markups. You may update the title to emphasize the error text (quotes ?) The error text seems very clear : for some reason your table could not be found as @K.Rogers pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

The database name you specify in database.php is `teamspan_pcrequest`. You should change it to only `pcrequest` based on the screenshot you sent from PhpMyAdmin.

[image: Database Name]

Comment: When I uploaded it to CPanel it becomes teamspan_pcrequest so I changed all my connections to teamspan_pcrequest. That was my DB Schema from the wamp server sorry

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot from PhpMyAdmin of the CPanel?